# AutoHotkey Keybindings seems to override

Tags: autohotkey

### The Goal

I'm trying to rebind my keyboard so that the keyboard shortcuts work similar to a Mac's; specifically, `Alt` + `key` results in `Cmd`(Ctrl) + `Key`.

#### Snippet

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SendMode Input
LAlt::LCtrl
```

And that works perfectly!

### The Problem

The problem comes into play when I try to change `Alt`+`Tab` (Now triggering as `Ctrl`+`Tab`) to fire as the original `AltTab` functionality.

#### Snippet

```
LAlt & Tab::Send AltTab
```

or even

```
LAlt & Tab::AltTab
```

seems to work (may work)  but it seems to override the previous `Alt`+`Key` Functionality and `Alt` will function normally.

### Desired Result

`Alt`+`s` => `Ctrl`+ `s`

`Alt`+`n` => `Ctrl`+ `n`

`Alt`+`o` => `Ctrl`+ `o`

`....`

`Alt`+`tab` => `AltTab`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong / missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefining modifier keys is not documented well enough. There is nothing in the [documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) about `LAlt & Tab::AltTab`(Note that this is the correct way, `LAlt & Tab::Send AltTab` will just send the string "*AltTab*") cancelling the `LAlt::LCtrl` remapping so I can't tell you exactly what the problem is. I did manage to solve it in the following way:

```
LAlt::LCtrl
LAlt up::Send {LAlt up}

#if GetKeyState("LAlt", "P")
*Tab::Send {LAlt down}{tab}
*+Tab::Send {LAlt down}{ShiftDown}{tab}{ShiftUp}
#If
```

It can send some unneeded key up events but from what I saw works well.

Comment: Awesome! This seems to work! Only problem I'm experiencing with it that my Right Shift doesn't active the shift tab. Any ideas why that would be ?

Comment: @Jujunol Not sure, might be a bug. I made a small change that fixes the problem.